# Plex Media Server web page showing "Secure Connection Failed"

Tags: plex

I just created a new Plex Media Server as a Docker container using linuxserver/plex following [this](https://youtu.be/F7WveUXlBEY). Immediately after creating it, I tried to access the web interface at https://localhost:32400 and receive the following error:

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:32400. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
```

I've recreated the container multiple times and still get the same result.

This is after trying to create one using plexinc/pms-docker. With the plexinc/pms-docker container, I was able to access the web interface but had to rebuild it and received the same "Secure Connection Failed" error when rebuilding it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using http, rather than https?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox by any chance? If so, first try using something else.
This is seemingly a Firefox only error and if you have to use Firefox make sure "Enable DNS over HTTP" is unticked in network settings.
There is a whole list of other things to try too.
Try here for instance: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/pr-end-of-file-error/